# How can I debug Electron shell using the breakpad symbols in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, electron, google-breakpad

As the title says, I'm looking at a heisenbug crash deep within Electron Shell / node.js and all I have are the "symbols" I can download from the [release page](https://github.com/atom/electron/releases).

Is there any way of converting these to PDB files? Or any other way to make VS show me a readable stack frame maybe with some parameters?

Edit: Alternatively, can I get more information from a dump file I could create with VS? Looking at breakpad I can't seem to figure out how to do anything useful with those symbol files.

BTW I'm using VS 2015.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible, you need the original PDBs :-/

Comment: Thanks, looking at breakpad I'm not sure how to use those symbol files at all. Do you know if I could get somewhere if I had a dump file generated by VS or Windows?